# Rails route 'stacking' (not sure what it's called)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, rails-routing

What's the problem here?:

```
get 'cars/index'                             <- works
get 'carsBLAH/index'                         <- Breaks!
get 'cars'        to: 'cars#index'           <- works
```

I assume it's some kind of rails magic / sugar, but I can't find anything about this type of situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define:

```
get 'carsBLAH/index'
```

By default Rails looks for `index` action within `CarsBLAHsController`.  It would break if:

1. `CarsBLAHsController` is not defined.
2. `CarsBLAHsController` exists but `index` method is not defined.

You could specify the `controller` and `action` to execute for a route with:

```
# executes CarsController#index
get 'carsBLAH/index', to: 'cars#index'
```

Suggest reading [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for details.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now... I thought there was something special about stacking the cars and cars/index routes in routes.rb.  What's actually happening is each line is independent, and the only reason cars/index doesn't need a `to:` is because cars#index happens to exist.  Thanks a bunch.